# ASP.NET MVC 4, use views or layouts to handle templating of content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a long time ASP.NET WebForms developer.  I'm familiar with MVC as a design pattern and have used it in many apps.  I'm a little surprised (and excited) about ASP.NET MVC as I am moving a PoC into beta form using ASP.NET MVC,

Architecturally speaking, I have content templates that I will be using on the site to present content in different layouts.  What will be the same across the board is that there will be images and text.  How it's presented will depend upon which layout (or skin) the author wishes to use.

Architecturally speaking, which of the two scenarios fits better with the framework?

For each layout I desire, I create a single View and a single View Controller where the VC gets the info from the Model (images/text) and gives it to the View.  The info from the model will depend on which article the user wants to see.  To use a different layout, the view served would be a different view that contains that layout, and it would use the same VM and same Model.

or

I create a layout that has the layout which is then used by the view to present the content.  The view could use a different layout to lay things out differently.  Each article would have it's own view and when that view is loaded, a determination is made (based on author intent) which layout to use as the layout for the view.  There would be multiple layouts that could be used.

Clearly both will do the job.  I am new to ASP.NET MVC, so I am wondering, architecturally, what has been done in the past by those architecting similar cases.

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as a "View Controller".  It's a Controller, a View, a View Model, and a Model.

Comment: It's common to use the terminology "View Controller" instead of "Controller" in other languages such as when using MVC within Objective-C.  I've been doing a lot of objective-C work lately..

Comment: I would question whether that was actually MVC then.  The idea of MVC is a separation of concerns between Model View and Controller.  The term "View Controller" suggest, much like View Model that it's a Controller for the view, but that's not the case in ASP.NET MVC, because the view is totally separate.  A controller action doesn't even have to have a view, or it can choose from many views, and a view can be used in many controllers.

Comment: It's MVC.  In MVC you basically need a Model, you need a controller, and because this is a UI pattern you absolutely need a view.  In Obj-C the same separation of concerns exist.  A view controller is basically a "controller for a view" which is how I read the naming convention.  It loads the view at run time.  It can load multiple different views, etc.  There is a separation of concerns, each VC can be used by multiple views if needed, and vice versa.

Comment: No, you don't need a view.  You can make calls in MVC that return void, and have no view at all.  You can have calls that return json, or xml, or Files.. in ASP.NET MVC, the view is a template that is rendered, that's pretty much it.  I'll say it again, there's no such thing as a "View Controller" in ASP.NET MVC.  You might have that term in some other implementation (just like other implementations don't have View Models), but in ASP.NET MVC, the Controller has virtually nothing to do with a view.  This is not just interchangeable terminology, there is semantic differences.

Comment: So that would be ASP.NET's implementation of it then.  The whole premise of MVC as a design pattern is that there is a view.  If ASP.NET MVC allows not having a view no problem.  I'll agree completely that it's a framework implementation detail.  I'l accept your argument about the terminology.  Controller it is.

Answer (score 0):

I crossed the same bridge a while back and found that building up core "Base" partial Layouts for particular functionality worked in my favor. If you define base partials then you have a solid foundation for partials that extend that particular functionality using Layouts, moreover, if your controllers send base models to your base layouts then extended partials can build up on top of that. Please note that I am making use of a lot of AjaxBeginForm or pushing back smaller content within a larger model so what is described may be overkill.